# Improve a query consisting multiple subqueries using joins

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, query-optimization

server_details

| hostname | category | active |
| --- | --- | --- |
| server1 | small | yes |
| server2 | big | yes |

server_stat

| hostname | metric | value | lastupdated |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| server1 | cpu | 10 | 03:30:37 |
| server1 | ram | 25 | 03:30:37 |
| server1 | disk | 57 | 03:30:37 |
| server2 | cpu | 23 | 03:30:37 |
| server2 | ram | 55 | 03:30:37 |
| server2 | disk | 33 | 03:30:37 |
| server1 | cpu | 13 | 03:25:37 |
| server1 | ram | 25 | 03:25:37 |
| server1 | disk | 43 | 03:25:37 |
| server2 | cpu | 83 | 03:25:37 |
| server2 | ram | 95 | 03:25:37 |
| server2 | disk | 63 | 03:25:37 |

Result should look like with latest lastupdated value

| hostname | category | active | cpu | ram | disk |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| server1 | small | yes | 10 | 25 | 57 |
| server2 | big | yes | 23 | 55 | 33 |

I am using SQL Server database
I wrote the below query and it is giving desired output

```
SELECT hd.hostname, hd.category, hd.active,
       (SELECT top 1 hs_cpu.value 
        FROM server_stat hs_cpu 
        WHERE hs_cpu.hostname = hd.hostname AND hs_cpu.metric = 'cpu' 
        ORDER BY hs_cpu.lastupdated DESC) AS cpu,
       (SELECT top 1 hs_ram.value 
        FROM server_stat hs_ram 
        WHERE hs_ram.hostname = hd.hostname AND hs_ram.metric = 'ram' 
        ORDER BY hs_ram.lastupdated DESC) AS ram,
       (SELECT top 1 hs_disk.value 
        FROM server_stat hs_disk 
        WHERE hs_disk.hostname = hd.hostname AND hs_disk.metric = 'disk' 
        ORDER BY hs_disk.lastupdated DESC) AS disk
FROM server_details hd;
```

Can we optimize this query using joins without subqueries?

Comment: why is it slow?

Comment: Please tag your question with the type of SQL database you use: these things differ 
 between make and version of database. Please [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/query-optimization/info) and [edit] your question or ask another. To help you with [tag:query-optimization] questions we need more information.

Comment: i wanted to use best optimized query for this requirement and the query I wrote is slow as well

Comment: It's technically possible to use CTEs instead of subqueries, but that would make matters worse. Well-written subqueries are not the enemy.

Comment: `LIMIT` isn't a T-SQL operator. If you're using SQL Server, then you're going to get an error.

Comment: you can use a pivot for this

Comment: @Stu Why was this closed, seems to have everything needed?

Comment: @Charlieface for optimization we need tables and indexes and an explain read the tag

Comment: @nbk OP does actually mean _Optimize_ in a performance sense, after recent edits this is more clear, they are asking for a different technique to achieve the same output without subqueries. So _Optimize_ here refers to writing and managing the SQL.

Comment: @Charlieface and there we differ i think it is vital to know exactly the table, to try to solve this question

Comment: @nbk for specific scenarios schema can help, but this one has a simple hypothetical schema clearly defined, we are talking about the query structure, not the _best execution plan_. This keeps this question in a space that is accessible to the community. I would be happy to see the [query-optimisation] tag removed if that helps get this re-opened, but that is the tag wiki fault for not making a clear distinction between performance tuning and simplifying the query syntax. It might not be clear to new players that the tag is _exclusively_ for __making queries run faster__

Comment: Almost there, what does slow mean.  Can you post some times ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this would actually be any *faster* but it is a slightly more set-oriented approach, using `PIVOT` and joining back to the details: https://dbfiddle.uk/Ebw30T90

```
select *
from
(
    SELECT Latest.hostname, sd.category, sd.active, latest.metric, v.value
    FROM (
        SELECT hostname,metric, MAX(lastupdated) lastupdated
        FROM server_stat
        GROUP BY hostname,metric
    ) as Latest
    INNER JOIN server_stat v ON Latest.hostname = v.hostname AND Latest.metric = v.metric AND Latest.lastupdated = v.lastupdated
    INNER JOIN server_details sd on Latest.hostname = sd.hostname
) x
pivot
(
  max(value)
  for metric in([cpu],[ram],[disk])
) pvt
```

| hostname | category | active | cpu | ram | disk |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| server1 | small | yes | 10 | 25 | 57 |
| server2 | big | yes | 23 | 55 | 33 |

---

The problem with this data, that makes it harder to use `PIVOT` is that the aggregate value (*In this case `lastupdated`*) is not the value that we want to see, instead we want a the `value` column from the corresponding row with the `MAX(lastupdated)`.

The key is to prepare the set that we want to `PIVOT` first, use `GROUP BY` in place of the `TOP 1` / `LIMIT 1`, and then join back to the `server_stat` table to get the `value`

```
SELECT Latest.hostname, sd.category, sd.active, latest.metric, v.value
FROM (
    SELECT hostname,metric, MAX(lastupdated) lastupdated
    FROM server_stat
    GROUP BY hostname,metric
) as Latest
INNER JOIN server_stat v ON Latest.hostname = v.hostname AND Latest.metric = v.metric AND Latest.lastupdated = v.lastupdated
INNER JOIN server_details sd on Latest.hostname = sd.hostname
```

*I have also included the `category` field from the `server_details` so that we don't have to re-query that and re-write out all the field names*

| hostname | category | active | metric | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| server2 | big | yes | ram | 55 |
| server2 | big | yes | disk | 33 |
| server2 | big | yes | cpu | 23 |
| server1 | small | yes | ram | 25 |
| server1 | small | yes | disk | 57 |
| server1 | small | yes | cpu | 10 |

---

**Update: Thanks to Joel Coehoorn!**

This is a thing of beauty ;) We can combine this approach with [this solution by Joel Coehoorn](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76722795/1690217) to eliminate the `GROUP BY` that joins back on itself to access the correlated data. I can't really comment on performance of *window queries* vs *group by*, but there is a lot less code to manage this way.

```
select *
from
(
    -- Thanks Joel Coehoorn!
    SELECT distinct sd.hostname, sd.category, sd.active, metric
       , first_value(value) over (partition by sd.hostname, ss.metric 
                              order by lastupdated desc) value
    FROM Server_Details sd
    INNER JOIN Server_Stat ss on ss.hostname = sd.hostname
) x
pivot
(
  max(value)
  for metric in([cpu],[ram],[disk])
) pvt
```

> Updated Fiddle: (look at the last query) https://dbfiddle.uk/7D9lGpZI

Comment: The best result is probably a combination of our two approaches: use `first_value()` or `row_number() = 1` instead of an extra JOIN, and feed that into the `PIVOT` instead of repeating the expressions with distinct

Comment: thanks @JoelCoehoorn I agree, it felt like window query could do this, but didn't think of `first_value()`

Comment: Okay, here's the result: https://dbfiddle.uk/G9zTsEDI  Unfortunately, no good way to benchmark this.

Comment: You beat me to it, It doesn't come up a lot, but I'm going to use this next time and give it a good profiling.

Comment: "Doesn't come up a lot". Anywhere you've got an EAV pattern, you'll eventually want to do this. But good DB designers avoid EAV, so there you go ;)

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn row-numbering inside an APPLY might be a good option https://dbfiddle.uk/pp4uUsRM

Comment: @Charlieface I was about to disagree, but `distinct` ... `first_value()` still needs to operate for each row, so it probably looks the same as `row_number()`...`where rn=1`.

Comment: without writing distinct keyword it is giving same output. what is the purpose of using distinct https://dbfiddle.uk/7D9lGpZI here in the last query - @JoelCoehoorn

Comment: @PavanG the `partition by` expression with the `first_value` function does not fully act as a `GROUP BY` on it's own. It defines a group, but doesn't actually roll up the rows. So without the `DISTINCT`, we still get the same number of rows as if we had just done a simple join. However, it does mean the `first_value()` function will show the same result in many of the rows, so when we add `distinct` it can roll everything up and get the desired results.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn okay, tnx for the clarification

Answer (score 1):

I would expect this to do a little better:

```
SELECT distinct sd.hostname, sd.category, sd.active
   , first_value(value) over (partition by sd.hostname 
                              order by case when metric = 'cpu' then 0 else 1 end, lastupdated desc) cpu
   , first_value(value) over (partition by sd.hostname
                              order by case when metric = 'ram' then 0 else 1 end, lastupdated desc) ram
   , first_value(value) over (partition by sd.hostname
                              order by case when metric = 'disk' then 0 else 1 end, lastupdated desc) disk
FROM Server_Details sd
INNER JOIN Server_Stat ss on ss.hostname = sd.hostname
```

See it here:

> https://dbfiddle.uk/gW2-L_-4

You can might also do a little better still via `PIVOT`, but whenever you need to look at the data like this to find out about your columns there's no avoiding needing to repeat some ugly code to get each column value.